# Prove that if G is hamiltonian then Line graph of G is hamiltonian too

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Prove that if G is hamiltonian then Line graph of G is hamiltonian too

I know that we have a closed path with all vertices included then because every edge in this path is connected to two other edges then there will be a hamiltonian cycle in L(G) too and if we add the edges which are not in hamiltonian cycle L(G) is still hamiltonian

Answer (score 0):

Assume $G$ has a hamiltonian path $v_0,\dots, v_{n-1}$, where $v_{n-1}$ is adjacent to $v_0$.

For each $0\leq i \leq {n-2}$ we can consider the path $P_i$ in $L(G)$ that contains all edges in $G$ incident to $v_i$ such that the other vertex is $v_k$ with $k > i$ and such that the edges appear in decreasing order of $k$, so that the last element is always $\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}$

Since the last element of $P_i$ is $\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}$ the path $P_0,P_1,\dots, P_{n-2}$  is a path in $L(G)$ and one can check it contains every vertex in $L(G)$ exactly once. the first vertex is $\{v_0,v_{n-1}\}$ and the last vertex is $\{v_{n-2},v_{n-1}\}$, these last two vertices are adjacent in $L(G)$, so this is in fact a hamiltonian cycle of $L(G)$.

Comment: Can you explain this simpler? I will be so helpful for me thanks

Comment: First let me try to understand what your proposed solution is.  I think your idea is that the result is true when $G$ is a cycle and that it must also be true when we add even more edges to $G$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean

Comment: that solution can work but you need to be careful, you need to make sure that you do it in such a way that for after you add a new (u,v) it still happens that in the hamiltonian graph in L(G) , for each vertex x there is still a pair of adjacent edges that both have x in the graph. If you do that then you can grow it like you say. One way to assure that is what I'm doing.

Comment: Do you have telegram or something I really need this

Comment: Onir, please search for duplicates when a question is as common as this question is; and do so before answering.  Unfortunately, this question was asked and answered already.

Comment: "as common" lol