# Show that if $G$ is Hamiltonian, then $L(G)$ is Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if $G$ is Hamiltonian, then $L(G)$ is Hamiltonian.

**Attempt:**

For any graph, we can relabel the vertices.

[image]

For a graph $G$, then we must have a Hamiltonian cycle $(1, 2, \ldots , n)$. Now, I think it is just a matter of guaranteeing that in $L(G)$ there is a cycle $((1,2), (2,3), \ldots )$.

Comment: It's just a hint, something like what I've already done, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: The hint is effectively a full answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152380/prove-that-if-g-is-hamiltonian-then-line-graph-of-g-is-hamiltonian-too/4152433#4152433